# Routes for rails model controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a site and want to have a blog section on it. However, i don't want to blog to be situated on the index page of the site.

I created a model and generated a controller and followed the instructions on https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-blog-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1

The only thing i didn't follow was this code:
    #config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "posts#index"
 resources :posts
end
```

I want to get to the posts page by localhost:3000/posts/

My roots are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
get 'pages/index' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end


resources :posts do
  resources :index
  resources :show
  resources :edit
  resources :new
  resources :form
end
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
match 'posts' => 'posts#index'
```

Comment: I used the get function and that worked to display that page.

I'm also trying to get a link for show, edit and new. Do i use that same style?

Answer (score 0):

Your below routes are wrong:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :index
  resources :show
  resources :edit
  resources :new
  resources :form
end
```

See the steps below. After below steps, you should run `rails routes` command for seeing all routes.

**First option:**

```
resources :posts, only: [:index]
```

For other action like show, edit.

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :edit]
```

For all actions:

```
resources :posts
```

**Second option:**

For singular resources, you can use like the below:

```
get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'
```

For more info about Rails routes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code you provided.  First, the final "end" statement should be after your resources block for :posts.  Second, the resources block should be simplified to just

```
resources :posts
```

As in the example provided.  You are currently using "nested resources", which is not what you are going for.  Here is a description of nested resources to give you an idea of how they are used:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

These two changes should get you moving in the right direction.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your routes definition. It should be.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
  get 'pages/index' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
  root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts
end
```